# Удаление записи в таблице СУБД

Tags: php

//index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>test_number_2</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="test2.php", method="post">
    <div align="center">
        <table>
            <tr bgcolor="#00FF99" align="center">
                <td colspan="2">
                    Table
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#00FF99" align="center">
                <td>
                    Name<br>
                    <input type="text" name="Name">
                </td>
                <td>
                    Age<br>
                    <input type="text" name="Age">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#00FF99" align="right">
                    <input type="submit" value="Добавить" name="onAdd">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
<?php
    require_once "mysql_connect.php";
    $name=$_POST['Name'];
    $age=$_POST['Age'];
    $submit_add=$_POST['onAdd'];
    if(isset($submit_add)){

    $result= mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_one (Id, Name, Age) VALUES ('','$name', '$age')");
    //Если запрос пройдет успешно то в переменную result вернется true
    if($result == 'true') {
        echo "Ваши данные успешно добавлены";
        }
    else {
        echo "Ваши данные не добавлены";
        }
    }
    echo "<br><br>";
    $result=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `table_one`');// делаем выборку из таблицы
    $del;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))// берем результаты из каждой строки
    { 
        //echo '<p>Запись №:'.$row['Id'].'. Имя: '.$row['Name'].'. Возраст: '.$row['Age'].'.</p>';// выводим данные
        echo '<table bgcolor="#00CCFF"><tr><td><input type="hidden" name="id_t'.$row['Id'].'" value="№'.$row['Id'].'"></td><td><input type="text" name="name_t'.$row['Id'].'" value="Имя: '.$row['Name'].'"></td><td><input type="text" name="age_t'.$row['Id'].'" value="Возраст: '.$row['Age'].'"></td><td><input type="submit" name="delete" value="Удалить"></td></tr></table>';

        if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
            $del=$row['Id'];
            echo $del;
            $delete="DELETE FROM table_one WHERE Id=$del";
            mysql_query($delete);
        }
    }
    echo $del;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

//mysql_connect.php

```
<?php ## Подключение к СУБД MySQL.

$user = "root";

$pass = "";

$db = "db";

// Подключаемся к СУБД MySQL. 
mysql_connect("localhost", $user, $pass)

or die("Could not connect: ".mysql_error()) ; 
// Создаем БД $db — это может делать только суперпользователь! 
// Если БД уже существует, будет ошибка, но это не страшно. 
@mysql_query ( 'CREATE DATABASE $db');

// Выбираем БД $db (только что созданную или уже существующую). 
mysql_select_db($db)

or die("Could not select database: ".mysql_error());

?>
```

Собственно вопрос, как правильно организовать кнопку удаления? В моём "бредо-коде", цикл прокрутиться и даже не посмотрит была ли нажата какая-либо в нём кнопка. 
P.S. Нуждаюсь в свежей идее. (Новичёк)

Answer (score 1):

Я особо не вникал но на сколько понял в самом принципе кнопок "удалить" отсутствует форма:
Может быть нужно для начала так или что-то вроде этого

```
echo '<table bgcolor="#00CCFF"><tr><td><input type="hidden" name="id_t'.$row['Id'].'" value="№'.$row['Id'].'"></td><td><input type="text" name="name_t'.$row['Id'].'" value="Имя: '.$row['Name'].'"></td><td><input type="text" name="age_t'.$row['Id'].'" value="Возраст: '.$row['Age'].'"></td><td><form бла-бла-бла><input type="hidden" name="id" value="$id"><input type="submit" name="delete" value="Удалить"></form></td></tr></table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну, если вам нужна идея - я напишу, но без кода:

Вообще, удаление чего-либо, лучше, никогда не делать на GET. Вам лучше первую колонку в таблице сделать chekbox,ом для возможностью выбора нескольких записей, в данном случае для удаления. А удаление сделать на JS, допустим на том же JQuery. При нажатии спрашиваем, "Уверены что хотите удалить 5 записей?" если человек выбирает "Да" то формируете POST запрос на отдельный скрипт(если у вас разделение по файлам) и обрабатываете POST переменные. Такой упрощённый AJAX получается.

Я бы как-то так делал.